# Automatically update the file path of Vlookup to the newest workbook added to a folder

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup, powerquery

Hello each month we receive a series of monthly returns from different accounts which go into a designated folder based on the account name. Each return has the new month's returns appended to all the previous monthly returns. I am running a vlookup function on my workbook based on the specific return I am looking for. Is it possible to change the source on the vlookup function so it takes the data from the most recently added file in the folder, that way it will contain all the most recent return data with all the previous returns?
Thanks

Comment: So, to be clear yhe path stays the same and the name changes? If you can predict the name for each month then that is an easy task based on the month. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. The first step should be to connect to the designated folder. You should see then something like this:
[image]

**Option 1: If the file contains the month** 

If your file contains the month you can use it to extract this information. Following the example above you could:

1. extract the first 7 charactes and parse it to a date.
2. sort the date in descending order, so the latest file will be on top
3. use keep rows to get rid of the rest of files
4. with the last file remaining, expand the content

**Option 2: Use file properties** 

When you connect to a folder you can see the field "Date created". Use this the same way as explained in option 1.

**Option 3: Remove duplicates** 

If for whatever reason the two options above are not possible, depending on your data you can:

1. join all files which will lead to duplicates
2. filter duplicates

This third option might not work if you could have two registers which look the same (all columns in the row have the same value) can appear in your dataset.